# Fabric JS Filters

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I've been working on filters for fabric JS and have created my own which seemed to work great.

I followed this example and its worked fine in the past.
http://fabricjs.com/image-filters/

But for some reason now it throws an error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: f is not defined

```
 var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c',
                            {
                                isDrawingMode: false
                            }),
                            f = fabric.Image.filters;



$('ul.swatches li').click(function (event)
{
     color = this.getAttribute("data-color");
     var dataState = this.getAttribute("data-state");
     applyFilter(2, true && new f.RemoveColor({
            threshold: 190,
            color: color
     }));
  });

function applyFilter(index, filter)
{
    var obj = canvas.item(0);
    obj.filters[index] = filter;
    obj.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
}
```

Comment: Where is the code defining `f` variable?

Comment: Updated code sorry, its hard to show due to how its built

Comment: Can I show you code on something like teamviewer?

Comment: when it stopped working? did you update fabricjs version?

Comment: No but structure of the code is completely different.

Comment: Everything works apart from filters :(

Comment: Ok i do not understand. When was it working and when it stopped. If you can explain i can help.